# Json to C# double datatype value returing 0

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
"{\"code\":200,\"status\":\"success\",\"message\":\"Live Tracking data fetched Successfully.\",\"data\":{\"location\":{\"latitude\":19.208087,\"longitude\":73.103965,\"speed_mps\":0,\"bearing\":0,\"altitude\":0,\"timestamp\":1504961984900},\"status\":\"offline\"}}"
```

Above is my json Output

I want This as a string and split format
where ,
latitude = 19.208087
longitude = 73.103965
etc

```
public class Location
{

    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
    public int speed_mps { get; set; }
    public int bearing { get; set; }
    public int altitude { get; set; }
    public long timestamp { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public Location location { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

Deserializing code:

```
var client = new WebClient(); var text = 
client.DownloadString("app.rollr.io:4032/…); 
Location Loc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Location>(text); 
Response.Write("Location" + Loc.longitude);
Response.Write("Location" + Loc.latitude);
```

The problem is that I'm getting 0 for the different fields

Comment: Question is unclear.. What do you wnat? What have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: var client = new WebClient();
                var text = client.DownloadString("https://app.rollr.io:4032/live-track?api_key=LMnxG6xvzn9hNnv3BpgerC8QTT5L4Y8m&serial_number=170####");

                Location Loc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Location>(text);
                Response.Write("Location" + Loc.longitude);
                Response.Write("Location" + Loc.latitude);

Comment: public class Location
    {
        
        public double latitude { get; set; }
        public double longitude { get; set; }
        public int speed_mps { get; set; }
        public int bearing { get; set; }
        public int altitude { get; set; }
        public long timestamp { get; set; }
    }

Comment: I have nominated for this question to be reopened as I can see what you are looking for.  Please have a look here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Comment: Use *RootObject* when deserializing,,, `var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(text);`

Comment: Thanks L.B It worked

Comment: @L.B Please make it an answer now that we have reopen it.

Comment: C#: can you guide how to get the google map on webform using above values of latlng?

Answer (score 0):

Use *RootObject* when deserializing...

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(text);
```

to access to location : `root.data.location`